# How to create border of the same size for different size symbols?

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) icons and their `fa-border` style:

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x fa-border icon-blue"></i>
<i class="fa fa-question fa-5x fa-border icon-grey"></i>
```

But the size of border created depends on the symbol size (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/zxVhL/1/)). How can I make it always square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the `height` and `width` of the `i` element explicitly, to make it square there is a trick using `:after` pseudo-element and with that trick, you just need to specify the `width` (no need to specify the `height`), this will help you maintain the page better in case you want to change the square size:

**CSS**:

```
i { 
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
/*only :after works*/
i:after {
  content:'';
  padding-top:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxVhL/7/)

Comment: If you use fa-rotate, you need to specify both width and height of equal values to consistently get a square. If you want non-square rectangles and use fa-rotate, you'll probably need to specify an inline style that applies the "height" and "width" correctly for the context of the rotation you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a width in css and center text

```
i.fa {
    width:70px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zxVhL/3/

Answer (score 1):

I would just get the largest possible size and set them all to be at least that large.  Then center your "text"

```
i { min-width:74px; text-align:center; }
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/zxVhL/4/ - DEMO**